# Return union of all rectangles

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, rectangles

I'm kinda new to Java and have a problem I just can't wrap my head around.

- **union (Rectangle ... rectangles)** should return the rectangle given by the
  Union of all rectangles. If rectangles is empty, return null.

I've created a helper-Method to compute the union of 2 Rectangles and then somehow tried to integrate it into the union-Method with no success. I kinda have to do the same for the **intersection** of 2 Rectangles but also can't get it done.

Could you guys give me some help? Below is my code.

```
public class Rectangle {
    int x, y, width, height;

    public Rectangle(int xInput, int yInput, int widthInput, int heightInput) {
        if (xInput <= 0 || yInput <= 0 || widthInput <= 0 || heightInput <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.x = xInput;
        this.y = yInput;
        this.width = widthInput;
        this.height = heightInput;

    }

    public static Rectangle union(Rectangle... rectangles) {
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (rectangles.length != 0) {
            for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
                s = unionOfTwo(s, r);
            }
            return s;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

     public static Rectangle unionOfTwo(Rectangle rec1, Rectangle rec2) {

        int x1 = Utils.min(rec1.x, rec2.x);
        int x2 = Utils.max(rec1.x + rec1.width, rec2.x + rec2.width) - x1;
        int y1 = Utils.min(rec1.y, rec2.y);
        int y2 = Utils.max(rec1.y + rec1.height, rec2.y + rec2.height) - y1;
        return new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should define `s` as the first rectangle before the `for` loop, then update it in each iteration with `unionOfTwo(s,r)` and return it after the loop has completed.

Comment: Hmm, I just did that. It still says: "Union of two overlapping rectangles is not computed correctly". Could it be that my algorithm to compute the union of 2 Rectangles is wrong?

Comment: Your computation of `y2` is wrong, the second argument to `max` should be `rec2.y + rec2.height`.

Comment: What does *"the rectangle given by the Union of all rectangles"* mean, more specifically? A union of rectangles is generally not a rectangle itself. Do you mean the minimum bounding rectangle?

Comment: Yes! The minimum bounding rectangle.

Comment: Alright. How about *"with no success"* - what specifically isn't working? Can you give an example of an input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: I just edited the code! Honestly, I really don't know where the problem is. When I test the code I just get: "Union of two overlapping rectangles is not computed correctly ". e.g. Input for union of (1,4,2,3) & (2,5,3,3) should give (1,5,4,4)

Comment: Is it possible that your rectangles are not represented the same way as in your example data? If they are (x,y,w,h) where x,y are the top-left corner and w,h are in the right and down directions, then the union of (1,4,2,3) and (2,5,3,3) should be (1,4,4,4), not (1,5,4,4).

Comment: No it's actually (1,5,4,4) you can even try it geometrically which I did. The problem is that I get from (1,4,2,3) union (2,5,3,3) = (0,0,5,-8) which is completely wrong... not even close!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public static Rectangle union(Rectangle... rectangles) {
    Rectangle s = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); // <-- wrong
    if (rectangles.length != 0) {
        for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
            s = unionOfTwo(s, r);
        }
        return s;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is because if your rectangles don't overlap (0, 0), you will get a wrong result. There are several ways to fix it, here is one of them:

```
public static Rectangle union(Rectangle... rectangles) {
    Rectangle s = null;
    for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
        if (s == null)
            s = r;
        else
            s = unionOfTwo(s, r);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Convert all rectangles to the [XMin, XMax] x [YMin, YMax] representation.
- Find the minimum of the minima and maximum of the maxima.
- Convert back to the [XMin, Width] x [YMin, Height] representation.

---

For the intersection of all rectangles, proceed analogously, but instead

- Find the maximum of the minima and the minimum of the maxima

and if Width or Height turns out to be negative, the intersection is void.